# How do I add the IDENTITY property to existing SQL Azure table?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, identity-column

I have created a couple of tables in SQL Azure and forgot to mark the primary keys as `identity` columns. There is no data in the tables yet, but the check box marked `Is Identity` is disabled.

How do I make an existing primary key an `identity` column in SQL Azure?

Comment: what's stopping you deleting and recreating an empty table?

Comment: Nothing, but I'm curious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You create a new table. You can't change the IDENTITY property in a regular SQL Server instance either - well, depending on your settings, SSMS might let you, but it doesn't tell you what it actually does behind the scenes - drops the table and re-creates it. Don't believe me? Script it out or profile it.

Comment: Very interesting; I always disable the SSMS warnings about dropping tables and never realized when it might have to do that in the background.